# What type of mint do I have?

Tags: identification, mint

I just received this mint plant but I do not know what type of mint it is. To me it smells like a light earthy mint and the stem looks purplish.

The biggest leaves are 2.5" in length and the width is 1".

[image: mint top]
[image: mint]

Comment: The purplish stems may not be significant, especially as the underside of the leaves is seems to be green rather than purple - the stems on older growth on many mint varieties can turn this colour over time.

Comment: Please consider [merging your unregistered and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and most importantly [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!